# Nested Object Acess to properties from Origin Object

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

Considering the following scheme.

A class that contains an object, in this case I'm using `OriginObject`.

The main problem is that the property NestedName has to access instructions about its behavior from another property within the OriginObject, in that case I thought about using reflection but, it's getting really confused.

The problem:

```
public class OriginObject
{
    public NestedObject nestedObject { get; set; }
    public Instructions Instruct { get; set; }
    public class NestedObject
    {
        public string NestedName { get; set; }
        public void GetName()
        {
            NestedName = //this.instruct.Name? being "this" the OriginObject;
        }
    }
    public struct Instructions
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
public void GetName()
{
    NestedName = GetType().DeclaringType
                 .GetProperty("instruct")
                 .GetValue(GetType().DeclaringType)
                 .GetType()
                 .GetProperty("Name")
                 .GetValue(wtf im doing);
}
```

I know I can simply add a parameter that provides me the Origin Object but, in my logical base knowledge this means Clean and beautiful code:

*/`Target.DoSomething( );`/*
or in production terms speaking it will be something like
Body.Parse( );

Does somebody know any other way to do this? Without creating an ilegal crime of sequential methods?

If it's just a bad idea I can change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand that this is some code that you're just playing around with and that you're not *really* looking at having three classes to encapsulate one string...

With your code as it is, an instance of `OriginObject.NestedObject` does not hold onto a reference to an instance of `OriginObject`.

Having your classes nested is nice if you want to be able to access *nonpublic* members (methods, etc.) but everything in your code is public so there's no benefit there.

As there's no coupling (`OriginObject.NestedObject` and `OriginObject.Instructions` don't access any methods or static members on `OriginObject`) your code is equivalent to how they would be if there was no nesting.

You can probably see why your code won't work if you rewrite `NestedObject` and `Instructions` to not nested - you'd have this equivalent code:

```
public class OriginObject
{
    public NestedObject nestedObject { get; set; }
    public Instructions Instruct { get; set; }
}

public class NestedObject
{
    public string NestedName { get; set; }

    public void GetName()
    {
        NestedName = // How is NestedObject supposed to get anything from OriginObject?
    }
}

public struct Instructions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

---

One fix would be to pass in an instance of `OriginObject` to a constructor of `NestedObject`, e.g.

```
public class OriginObject
{
    public NestedObject Nested { get; set; }
    public Instructions Instruct { get; set; }

    public class NestedObject
    {
        private OriginObject _origin;

        public NestedObject(OriginObject origin)
        {
            _origin = origin;
        }

        public string NestedName
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public void GetName()
        {
            NestedName = _origin.Instruct.Name;
        }
    }

    public struct Instructions
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You'd then do something like this:

```
var instructions = new OriginObject.Instructions() { Name = "Test" };
var origin = new OriginObject() { Instruct = instructions };
var nested = new OriginObject.NestedObject(origin);
nested.GetName();
```

---

That was a bit clunky though - you have to pass in the `OriginObject` to the `OriginObject.NestedObject`, but you only *ever* use it to access the `Instructions` property. It'd be better if you just passed the `Instructions` object directly into the constructor, e.g.:

```
public class OriginObject
{
    public NestedObject Nested { get; set; }
    public Instructions Instruct { get; set; }

    public class NestedObject
    {
        private Instructions _instructions;

        public NestedObject(Instructions instructions)
        {
            _instructions = instructions;
        }

        public string NestedName
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public void GetName()
        {
            NestedName = _instructions.Name;
        }
    }

    public struct Instructions
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

which you'd use with something like this:

```
var instructions = new OriginObject.Instructions() { Name = "Test" };
var origin = new OriginObject() { Instruct = instructions };
var nested = new OriginObject.NestedObject(instructions);
nested.GetName();
```

---

Now, it's a bit weird to have a `GetName()` method that you have to call each time and doesn't return anything. Better still might be to get rid of the `GetName()` method and have the `NestedName` property a computed property instead:

```
public class OriginObject
{
    public NestedObject Nested { get; set; }
    public Instructions Instruct { get; set; }

    public class NestedObject
    {
        private Instructions _instructions;

        public NestedObject(Instructions instructions)
        {
            _instructions = instructions;
        }

        public string NestedName
        {
            get
            {
                return _instructions.Name;
            }
        }
    }

    public struct Instructions
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

You'd then call that with an arguably simpler bit of code:

```
var instructions = new OriginObject.Instructions() { Name = "Test" };
var origin = new OriginObject() { Instruct = instructions };
var nested = new OriginObject.NestedObject(instructions);
```

---

At this point you might as well have a constructor for `OriginObject` too, so you know that the `Instructions` and the `NestedObject` instances are set - you could have something like this:

```
public class OriginObject
{
    public NestedObject Nested { get; set; }
    public Instructions Instruct { get; set; }

    public OriginObject(NestedObject nested, Instructions instruct)
    {
        Nested = nested;
        Instruct = instruct;
    }

    public class NestedObject
    {
        private Instructions _instructions;

        public NestedObject(Instructions instructions)
        {
            _instructions = instructions;
        }

        public string NestedName
        {
            get
            {
                return _instructions.Name;
            }
        }
    }

    public struct Instructions
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

which you'd use with some code like this:

```
var instructions = new OriginObject.Instructions() { Name = "Test" };
var nested = new OriginObject.NestedObject(instructions);
var origin = new OriginObject(nested, instructions);
```

---

Note that there's *still* no need for any nested types: you could have this equivalent code without nesting:

```
public class OriginObject
{
    public NestedObject Nested { get; set; }
    public Instructions Instruct { get; set; }

    public OriginObject(NestedObject nested, Instructions instruct)
    {
        Nested = nested;
        Instruct = instruct;
    }
}

public class NestedObject
{
    private Instructions _instructions;

    public NestedObject(Instructions instructions)
    {
        _instructions = instructions;
    }

    public string NestedName
    {
        get
        {
            return _instructions.Name;
        }
    }
}

public struct Instructions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

which would be called with code like the following:

```
var instructions = new Instructions() { Name = "Test" };
var nested = new NestedObject(instructions);
var origin = new OriginObject(nested, instructions);
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the support! You're completely Right. I think i nested things because of organization but as you described that's making things harder. So, Thank you so much i'll probably unest everything